# Deleted mobile number keeps returning Galaxy S4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, google-account

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S4, running ICS.

I keep my details including my own mobile number in my contacts.

Whenever I go to look at it, there's another number included (I think it's one I had a while ago) which makes it hard for me to remember which is mine!

I've checked my Google account and that only has one number for me.

I delete the number, but if I check a few days later it's back - any suggestions how I remove the number?

Comment: Are you syncing your contacts with anything else? Facebook, perhaps?

Comment: As far as I can tell I'm only syncing with my 2 Google accounts (which only have one mobile number for me) and the Samsung account stuff you can't remove. I disable everything to do with Facebook.

Comment: still a problem